# jQuery Anonymous Function Is Not Working With Global Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, global, anonymous-function

I'm trying to build a script that will remove DOM elements and add them back in their original places. I did some research and found a code snippet that looks like it should work. The only issue I'm having is that the global variables `LOelemsRemoved` and `LIelemsRemoved` are not retaining the values they get inside the `.each` anonymous function. The code is as follows:

```
var LOelemsRemoved = [];
var LIelemsRemoved = [];

function switchContent() {
    if (loggedIn()) {
        $(".logged-out").each(function (i, o) {
            elem = $(o);
            window.LOelemsRemoved.push({
                loc: elem.prev(),
                obj: elem.detach()
            });
            alert(LOelemsRemoved.length); //returns the correct values for each iteration
            alert('removed LO elems');
            window.LOelemsRemoved = LOelemsRemoved;
        });
        alert(LIelemsRemoved.length); //outputs 0
        while (LIelemsRemoved.length) {
            elem = elemsRemoved.pop();
            elem.loc.after(elem.obj);
            alert("added LI elems");
        }
    } else {
        $(".logged-in").each(function (i, o) {
            elem = $(o);
            window.LIelemsRemoved.push({
                loc: elem.prev(),
                obj: elem.detach()
            });
            alert(LIelemsRemoved.length); //returns the correct values for each iteration
            alert('removed li elems');
            window.LIelemsRemoved = LIelemsRemoved;
        });
        alert(LOelemsRemoved.length); //outputs 0
        while (LOelemsRemoved.length) {
            elem = elemsRemoved.pop();
            elem.loc.after(elem.obj);
            alert('added LOEleems');
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, both of the variables are declared outside of `switchContent()`. The 4 commented lines show which `alert` statements return which values. The ones inside the `.each` statements return the values they should. However, once the `.each` statement finishes execution, `LOelemsRemoved` and `LIelemsRemoved` both have length `0`. I'm guessing this is a scope issue because I'm using anonymous functions but I'm not extremely advanced with javascript so I'm not exactly sure what the scope issue is. Thanks!

Comment: Try to use the variable name without `window.` and it will use the closest one. Why is `elem` not declared, is it global?

Comment: In the `if` block, you are adding items to  `LOelemsRemoved`, not  `LIelemsRemoved`, so of course `LIelemsRemoved.length` will be `0`. It's vice versa in the `else` block. What else do you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I think I miscommunicated my idea. Basically, this is for switching the visible content without reloading the page once the user logs in to the website. When this happens, anything with the class logged-out should be removed, and anything with the class logged-in should be added. Vice versa when they log out. The reason I'm printing out LIelemsDeleted is because that's what needs to be added back in. I see what you mean though. So maybe an alternative solution to what I'm trying to do? The only thing is that I have to remove the DOM element because of some CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your vars definition is inside another function, in that case they'd be locally scoped. To make sure this doesn't happen, instead of this:

```
var LOelemsRemoved = [];
var LIelemsRemoved = [];
```

do this:

```
window.LOelemsRemoved = [];
window.LIelemsRemoved = [];
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but it didn't make a difference :( After reading the reply by @FelixKling I think that this may be a structural issue rather than a programmatic error. I think the solution I'm trying to use won't work for my purposes. I've replied to Felix's comment on what exactly I'm looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a similar yet slightly different method do accomplish this. As soon as the page loads, I run this:

```
window.$loggedInElements = $(".logged-in");
window.$loggedOutElements = $(".logged-out");
$loggedInElements.each(function(i,o) {
        var currElem = $(o);
        currElem.data("prev",currElem.prev());
    });

    $loggedOutElements.each(function(i,o) {
        var currElem = $(o);
        currElem.data("prev",currElem.prev());
    });
```

Then, in my `switchContent()` function, I have this code:

```
function switchContent() {
    if(loggedIn())
    {

        $loggedInElements.each(function(i,o) {
            var currElem = $(o);
            currElem.addClass("logged-in");
            currElem.insertAfter(currElem.data("prev"));
        });
        $loggedOutElements.each(function(i,o) {
            //alert($(o).attr("id"));
            $(o).removeClass("logged-out");
            $(o).detach();
        });
    }
    else
    {

        $loggedOutElements.each(function(i,o) {
            var currElem = $(o);
            currElem.addClass("logged-out");
            currElem.insertAfter(currElem.data("prev"));
        });
        $loggedInElements.each(function(i,o) {
            //alert($(o).attr("id"));
            $(o).removeClass("logged-in");
            $(o).detach();
        });
    }
}
```